# Вывод данных из ответа API

Tags: php, массивы

Возвращается посредством API ответ:

```
{
  "result": { 
    "Ads": [{  /* AdGetItem */
      "Id": (long),
      "CampaignId": (long),
      "AdGroupId": (long),
      "TextAd": {  /* TextAdGet */
        "Title": (string),
        "Title2": (string), /* nillable */ 
        "Text": (string),
        "AdExtensions": [{  /* AdExtensionAdGetItem */
          "AdExtensionId": (long), /* required */
          "Type": ( "CALLOUT" | "UNKNOWN" ) /* required */
        }, ... ],
      },
    }
  }
}
```

Нужно выдернуть массив AdExtensions, но вечно выдает ошибки:

> You can not use an object of type stdClass as an array

либо пустое значение.

Не могу вывести и через циклы пробовал, и преобразовывать в строку, объекты и другие варианты, не выводит. Наверняка делаю что то не так.

Работа со другими значении в строковом формате выводятся без проблем циклом (таким макаром):

```
foreach ($responseBody->result->Ads as $ads) {
  $title = $ads->TextAd->Title;
  $counthead2 = mb_strlen($ads->TextAd->Title2, 'utf-8');
  $counttext = mb_strlen($ads->TextAd->Text, 'utf-8');
  $countsimvds = mb_strlen($ads->TextAd->DisplayUrlPath, 'utf-8');
  $countsimv = mb_strlen($ads->TextAd->Title, 'utf-8');
}
```

а вот получить значения массива AdExtensions уже не могу, хотя в ответе они есть.

Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: надо преобразовать json-строку в массив, и работать с массивом

Comment: Будьте внимательны. Это массив объектов - [{ у него, следовательно $ads->TextAds->AdExtensions[0]->AdExtensionId

Comment: Да в том то и дело, проблема была более глобальная, и этот вариант пробовал и другие и преобразовывал, что только не делал все с ошибкой, помогла строчка error_reporting (0);  - Спасибо что отозвались на помощь

Answer (score -1):

В моей ситуации помогла строчка `error_reporting (0);`